# Android shared preferences not being saved

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferenceactivity

I got very simple preferences page in my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <CheckBoxPreference
       android:key="autoCheck"
       android:title="@string/autoCheckLbl"
       android:defaultValue="true"
       android:summary="@string/autoCheckDesc" 
    />   
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This settings file is managed by custom PreferenceActivity, which does nothing but:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

Problem is, when user make some change, i.e. check/uncheck that setting, it seems like that change isn't saved. For example, when user navigates back to the main activity, in which I'm retrieving current value of a *autoCheck* setting, this way:

```
boolean autoCheck = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getBoolean("autoCheck", true);
```

... retrieved value is not the one that was previously set by user. Only after the Android emulator is restarted, new value is correctly set.

Comment: Did you try to run this code on a real device?
The strange thing here is :
Only after the Android emulator is restarted, new value is correctly set.

Comment: Where are you running the above check? Are you sure it is being executed after you return from the preference activity? It should be in `onResume`.

Comment: Don't know how, but I resolved this problem by resetting data of my app in the emulator. Probably some bug of the Eclipse's Android emulator.